# Python errors, its a script and working on my main pc

Tags: python, python-3.x

Error

```
{'Username': 'zxc', 'Password': 'asdas'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 119, in <module>
    r"C:\Users\kini0801\Desktop\autopass\output.PNG", login_details["Username"],
  File "1.py", line 105, in add_text
    field = pyautogui.center(field)
  File "C:\Users\kini0801\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 550, in center
    return Point(coords[0] + int(coords[2] / 2), coords[1] + int(coords[3] / 2))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

full code. its supposed to like log you in on the account you choose directed at leauge of legends, you can delete edit, add and select account it works on my main pc but not on my laptop, and im supposed to show my teacher it. thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui
import clipboard
import time
from pywinauto import application

file_name = "accounts.csv"


def get_file_length(file_name):
    try:
        df_fun = pd.read_csv(file_name)
        ss = len(df_fun["Username"].tolist())
    except:
        return 0
    return ss


def append_data(data_dict_arg, file_name):
    p = get_file_length(file_name)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict_arg, index=[p])
    if p == 0:
        df.to_csv(file_name, mode="a+", header=True, encoding="utf-8", index=False)
    else:
        df.to_csv(file_name, mode="a+", header=False, encoding="utf-8", index=False)


def add_account():
    username = input("Enter Username: ")
    password = input("Enter Password: ")
    append_data({"Username": username, "Password": password}, file_name)


def get_accounts():
    file_df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    accounts_list = []
    for index, row in file_df.iterrows():
        accounts_list.append({"Username": row["Username"], "Password": row["Password"]})
    return accounts_list


def delete_account(username_arg):
    file_df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    file_df = file_df[file_df.Username != username_arg]
    file_df.to_csv(file_name, index=False, encoding="utf8")
    print("Successfully deleted:", username_arg)


def edit_account(old_username):
    username = input("Enter New Username:")
    password = input("Enter New Password:")
    file_df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    index = next(iter(file_df[file_df["Username"] == old_username].index), None)
    file_df.set_value(index, "Username", username)
    file_df.set_value(index, "Password", password)
    file_df.to_csv(file_name, index=False, encoding="utf8")
    print("Successfully Edited:", old_username)


def show_options(print_msg, data_dict_arg, print_msg_2):
    while True:
        index = 1
        print(print_msg)
        for keys_play in data_dict_arg:
            print(index, ": ", keys_play)
            index += 1
        try:
            index_new = int(input(print_msg_2))
            if index > index_new > 0:
                break
        except:
            pass
    return index_new


def display_menu(main_menu_opt):
    while True:
        main_option = show_options("Main Menu:", main_menu_opt, "Choose: ")
        if main_option == 1:
            accounts = get_accounts()
            user_names = [ac["Username"] for ac in accounts]
            index = show_options("All Accounts", user_names, "Choose:")
            print(accounts[index - 1])
            return accounts[index - 1]
        elif main_option == 2:
            add_account()
        else:
            accounts = get_accounts()
            user_names = [ac["Username"] for ac in accounts]
            index = show_options("All Accounts", user_names, "Choose:")
            if main_option == 3:
                edit_account(user_names[index - 1])
            elif main_option == 4:
                delete_account(user_names[index - 1])


def click_button(img):
    field = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img)
    field = pyautogui.center(field)
    pyautogui.leftClick(field.x, field.y)


def add_text(img, text):
    field = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(img)
    field = pyautogui.center(field)
    pyautogui.leftClick(field.x, field.y)
    pyautogui.typewrite(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_menu_options = {
        "Select Account": "",
        "Add Account": "",
        "Edit Account": "",
        "Delete Account": "",
    }
    login_details = display_menu(main_menu_options)
    add_text(
        r"C:\Users\kini0801\Desktop\autopass\output.PNG", login_details["Username"],
    )
    time.sleep(2)
    add_text(
        r"C:\Users\kini0801\Desktop\autopass\passwordpng.PNG",
        login_details["Password"],
    )
    time.sleep(2)
    click_button(r"C:\Users\kini0801\Desktop\autopass\btnpng.PNG")
    print("done")
```

login image on my main pc
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Nongaw-NM9U/maxresdefault.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHfnN.jpg the one i have on my laptop
tried fixing it the code above is what worked on my main pc so no changes, would appricate some help, cheers. love y'all.

Comment: So what does `...\autopass\output.PNG` look like? Since this image is used as a template to locate the input boxes it has to match the dialog. As the dialog looks different on your two PCs this template image should most likely also look different.

Comment: Main pc https://imgur.com/a/qcqVclo
laptop https://imgur.com/9dIfrbq

Comment: Well, start debugging... What is the output of `locateOnScreen` in the `add_text` method?

Comment: Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze__init__.py", line 550, in center
    return Point(coords[0] + int(coords[2] / 2), coords[1] + int(coords[3] / 2))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
this is all i get when bebugging it, the add_text is just printing in the username and password

Comment: You could debug using a debugger. Or at least print out the return value of `locateOnScreen`

Comment: Other users of this site might be interested on what the problem and the solutions was. You should consider adding this.

Comment: Yea will do just gonna fix some things up first, also can i mark the thread as resolved?

Comment: You can answer your own question, i.e. not comment here, but add an answer below. You can then accept your own answer and by this resolve the question.